# My website got hacked I need advice to clean

Tags: wordpress, indexing, cjk

My website got hacked and since 2 days I try to clean it, make it more secure as well as find how my website has been hacked.

My website had a lot of pages in japanese and now when I seach my website on google the first result is my website, but with the title and the description in japanese. I removed the sitemap.xml from my website as well as from the google search console.

I deleted all the weird files from the public_html directory and a ancrypted code from the header. I updated manually all the wordpress files and updated my theme. Removed almost all the plugins. I added some headers in the htacess like

> Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
>     Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
>     Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

I changed my passwords (database, google, hosting).
I installed wordfence and I scanned the website.

I also validated my website with the w3 validator.

Eveything seems ok, but what else should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a powerful anti Malware scanner to find malicious codes and scripts in affected files. 
To my experience this anti malware plugin is both cheap and powerful (Anti-Malware from GOTMLS.NET).
it's recommended to use admin protection plugin after updating all plugins and wordpress core files and themes.